# Get Error LNK2005 while linking libraries with vc++

Tags: visual-c++

I got a very confused error.

```
1>Base_d.lib(Base_d.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> >::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> >(class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > const &)" (??0?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z) already been defined in  ParametersManager.obj 
1>Base_d.lib(Base_d.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> >::~vector<int,class std::allocator<int> >(void)" (??1?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@QEAA@XZ)  already been defined in  ParametersManager.obj
```

Library "Base_d.lib" is a basic component library.
I am writing another library linked to "Base_d.lib" and the new library contains class "ParametersManager". The class

> "ParametersManager" has a member "std::vector< int > _mem"

I build this project on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015, tried many ways and rebuild for many times, and I found

> (1) if I commented the "_mem", the error disapperd.
>
> (2) if I a change "std::vector< int > _mem" to "std::vector< double > _mem", or any other type, the error will disappeared
>
> (3) build with linux ,the error disappeared ( but this work have to be used on windows)

I've been tortured for days, could any one help me?

Comment: That "basic component library" is a bit too basic, it must not export template classes like std:vector.

Comment: I checked code of Base_d.lib, it doesn't export std::vector, or typedef std::vector<int>

Comment: The linker is convinced it does.  You could use Dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL to get another opinion.

Comment: you are right, I tried dumpin.exe, and I found "14    D 00004B56 ??0?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z = @ILT+15185(??0?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z)"  What should I do next to find where it is defined?